# Wrong evaluation?

Tags: plotting, evaluation

In the code below, when I plot the mathematical expression on a specific interval, I can easily verify that the local maximum value is $ 5\times 10^{-8} $, but when I evaluate the expression in this point, I obtain a different value. Can someone identify what is wrong?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f0u = 500*10^6; f0d = 3.5*10^9;
f1u = 3.5*10^9; f1d = 500*10^6;
T = 0.1*10^-6;
ku = (f1u - f0u)/T;
kd = (f1d - f0d)/T;
phi0 = 0;
chplusu[t_] := E^(I*2*\[Pi]*((ku*t^2)/2 + f0u*t + phi0))
chplusd[t_] := E^(I*2*\[Pi]*((kd*t^2)/2 + f0d*t + phi0))
fsig1 = 1.6*10^9; fsig2 = 2.25*10^9; fsig3 = 3*10^9;
x[t_] := Cos[2*Pi*fsig1*t] + Cos[2*Pi*fsig2*t] + Cos[2*Pi*fsig3*t]
s1u[t_] := x[t]*chplusu[t]
s1d[t_] := x[t]*chplusd[t]
snu[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*(f0u*t + phi0))
snd[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*(f0d*t + phi0))
y2u[t_] := s1u[t]*snu[t]
y2d[t_] := s1d[t]*snd[t]
chmoinsu[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*((ku*t^2)/2 + f0u*t + phi0))
chmoinsd[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*((kd*t^2)/2 + f0d*t + phi0))
y1u[t_] := Convolve[y2u[to]*UnitStep[to], chmoinsu[to]*UnitStep[to], to, t, Assumptions -> t >= 0]
y1d[t_] := Convolve[y2d[to]*UnitStep[to], chmoinsd[to]*UnitStep[to], to, t, Assumptions -> t >= 0]
yu[t_] := y1u[t]*chplusu[t]
yd[t_] := y1d[t]*chplusd[t]
instante1 = (fsig1 - f0u)/ku
Out[]= 3.66667*10^-8
Plot[Evaluate[Re[yu[t] + yd[T - t]]], {t, instante1 - 0.5*10^-9, instante1 + 0.5*10^-9}, PlotRange -> Full, Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> {{instante1}, {Re[yu[instante1] + yd[T - instante1]]}}, ImageSize -> Full]
Re[yu[instante1] + yd[T - instante1]]
Out[]= 4.81281*10^-8
```

Comment: I suspect that there could be precision issues here, though I am not sure. I would try rationalizing all real numbers using Rationalize[val,0].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It IS an issue with precision ! Here are the code changes. Notice the removal of decimal 2.25* 10^9 and writing it as 225*10^7 and so on.

```
f0u = 500*10^6; f0d = 35*10^8;
f1u = 35*10^8; f1d = 500*10^6;
T = 1*10^-7;

fsig1 = 16*10^8; fsig2 = 225*10^7; fsig3 = 3*10^9;
```

Now we get:

```
Re[yu[instante1] + yd[T - instante1]]

(*     (-103731 Sqrt[3] + 32416384 π)/(1768166400000000 π) + (
 103731 Sqrt[3] + 55991936 π)/(1768166400000000 π)      *)

and 

In[87]:= N[%, 20]

Out[87]= 5.0000000000000000000*10^-8
```

Comment: Unbelievable! I would never imagine this. I thought that Mathematica addressed internal computations with maximum precision possible.

Comment: Well it does. But when we input Machine precision numbers (such as 2.25*10^9) it is forced to do computation in Machine Precision. Re-writing the same as 225*10^7 makes it an integer with infinite precision.